# Can I ask here about whether suspensions are justified?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

Can we post here to ask if users think a suspension was justified?

I was told too many flags but when asked for specifics no specifics were supplied.

Comment: I get to your network user page and found out that you are suspended to cool down in outdoors and bicycle, you might have to check your comments in both those accounts.

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar I (semi) get bicycle - not something I want to fight.   On TGO I was suspended for "too many flags" but when I asked for specifics was not given specifics.

Comment: Paparazzi - you have already had a second opinion from a separate moderator (twice), had many, many, many comments on specifics and then more general behaviour, and been recommended to contact the CMs. I'm not sure why you felt it necessary to also ask this here...

Comment: @RoryAlsop It is not necessary for you to understand.  This is an open site where I get to ask for input.  A post asking if I can post is pretty harmless.  I have already said OK on CM in a comment.

Comment: @Paparazzi You don't actually have a *right* to post here.  You may be given the *privilege* of posting here.  And of course your blatant lie that you weren't informed of why you were suspended isn't exactly "harmless".  That and the question is just a waste of our time; clearly you were already informed of why you were suspended, and who you can talk to if you want to discuss your suspension in more depth; asking us here is just wasting our time at best.

Comment: @Servy I am not asking if it was justified. I am asking if asking is OK and I have been told no and I am OK with that.

Comment: Note that all moderator messages (and responses) are automatically CC'ed to the SE CM team.

Comment: @enderland Thanks that helps. Not so much I want to contest the  suspension as record concerns. No way they are going to remove the suspension and I don't care if the time is reduced. I am not sure I even want to go back when the suspension ends. If I had known the CM team got a copy I would have packaged my response differently.  Ask if the suspension was justified is kind of something different and I have been told that would not be an appropriate question here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Suspensions are something between a user and the moderator. None of us regular users have the details to judge suspension cases. I don't believe suspensions are an invitation to start a discussion, they are more like an announcement.

And here on the Uber-meta we have no clue about the specific moderator team's customs/discussions, nor about the inappropriateness of the behavior of a user on a specific site. If there is a precedent they can bring it up on the site meta (if they are also suspended on meta wait till the suspension ended).

If there was really something done in error maybe the user can contact the team and explain their case. The link is at the bottom of every page.

Comment: On SO, one can get suspended on the main site but still be allowed on the per-site meta. Is that also the case for the smaller sites?

Comment: I was kind of hoping to get 3rd party feedback but will just go with "contact the team" if that is the proper process.

Comment: It seems you were suspended on two sites? Then you will already be in communication with a moderator. Note that messages you exchange with a moderator via that channel are accessible to all with moderation privileges (elected mods/employees), so you're already actively communicating with them.

Comment: @Bart This is about TGO.  I feel like there is not communication.   I ask for specifics and the response is too many flags.  If the correct action is "contact the team" then I am OK with that.

Comment: Sure, you always have that option. Good luck.

Comment: @S.L.Barth if you're suspended on main you're also suspended on that site's meta. If you come across a case where that isn't happening then it's a bug and needs addressing.

Comment: @rene - I wouldn't object to quotes round the word :) However, if you just roll back I'm not going to engage in an edit war.

Comment: @ChrisF maybe it is better this way. And it wasn't posted on Friday so no fun allowed yet. Cheers!

Comment: Hello, is that the fun police? Yes, I'd like to report someone attempting to joke about moderators outside of designated fun hours... you'll deal with it? Excellent, thanks.

Comment: @S.L.Barth - Per what ChrisF said, you might have seen this happen with one or two users in the last day or so on Meta.SO, and that was indeed a bug related to the HTTPS conversion. It should have been fixed, but if you see someone who is suspended on SO but not on Meta.SO, let one of us know.